# Run scrapy in background (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, scrapy

I managed to run a scrapy program in Ubuntu terminal. However, I cannot use Ctrl+Z and bg command to let it run in the background. It will close the spider connection everytime I press Ctrl + Z.

Is there any workaround or ways to solve the issue?

Comment: run it with `&` after like `python myscrapy.py &`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `nohup` together with `&`, with the following syntax:

```
nohup python parser.py &
```

While the `&` suffix gets it running in the background, closing the session would kill the process anyway. `nohup` creates a session-independent process, suitable for all kinds of environments (such as SSH sessions and remote servers, for example) and stores all console output in a log file.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your spider with `scrapy crawl`:

- If you want to keep the logs: `scrapy crawl my_spider > /path/to/logfile.txt 2>&1 &`
- If you want to dismiss the logs: `scrapy crawl my_spider > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screen` to run one or more task in the background